# how to scroll the desired columns of treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a GUI application where to some data will be fetched from the database and will be displayed in a treeview. But the problem is that my treeview has around 20 columns and that is way to much. I mean the whole application can't be fit in my screen.

So I want to display only 2-3 columns initially and I want the rest of the columns to be visible via scrollbar.

I have used "displaycolumns" options to display first 3 columns and I have created the scrollbar too but I am unable to figure out that how I can make the rest of columns visible via scrollbar.

The Following is my code, I have removed buttons method and database functionalities to simplify it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.font as tkFont

   class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
     tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    #Creating Geometry Of the window
    #self.geometry("500x500+0+0")
    self.title("Test Software")

    #Creating Labels

    self.agreement_number_label = tk.Label(text="Agreement Number")
    self.area_office_label = tk.Label(text="Area office")
    self.branch_label = tk.Label(text="Branch")
    self.customer_name_label = tk.Label(text="Customer Name")
    self.model_label = tk.Label(text="Model")
    self.registered_number_label = tk.Label(text="Registered Number")
    self.engine_number_label = tk.Label(text="Engine Number")
    self.chasis_number_label = tk.Label(text="Chasis Number")
    self.make_label = tk.Label(text="Make")

    #creating entry fields variables

    self.agreement_number = tk.StringVar()
    self.area_office = tk.StringVar()
    self.branch = tk.StringVar()
    self.customer_name = tk.StringVar()
    self.model = tk.StringVar()
    self.registered_number = tk.StringVar()
    self.engine_number = tk.StringVar()
    self.chasis_number = tk.StringVar()
    self.make = tk.StringVar()

    #creating Entry Fields

    self.agreement_number_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.agreement_number)
    self.area_office_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.area_office)
    self.branch_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.branch)
    self.customer_name_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.customer_name)
    self.model_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.model)
    self.registered_number_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.registered_number)
    self.engine_number_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.engine_number)
    self.chasis_number_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.chasis_number)
    self.make_entry = tk.Entry(textvariable = self.make)

    #Adding Labels and Entry Fields to the grid
    #1st Row Fields
    self.agreement_number_label.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(25,0),sticky="w",padx=(20,0))
    self.agreement_number_entry.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=(25,0),sticky="w")
    self.area_office_label.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=(25,0),sticky="w")
    self.area_office_entry.grid(row=0,column=3,pady=(25,0),sticky="w")
    self.branch_label.grid(row=0,column=4,pady=(25,0),sticky="w")
    self.branch_entry.grid(row=0,column=5,pady=(25,0),sticky="w",padx=(0,20))
    #2nd row fields
    self.customer_name_label.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w",padx=(20,0))
    self.customer_name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w")
    self.model_label.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="w")
    self.model_entry.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky="w")
    self.registered_number_label.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky="w")
    self.registered_number_entry.grid(row=1,column=5,sticky="w",padx=(0,20))
    #3rd Row Fields
    self.chasis_number_label.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w",padx=(20,0))
    self.chasis_number_entry.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="w")
    self.engine_number_label.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="w")
    self.engine_number_entry.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky="w")
    self.make_label.grid(row=2,column=4,sticky="w")
    self.make_entry.grid(row=2,column=5,sticky="w",padx=(0,20))

    #Creating a search button
    self.search_button = tk.Button(text = "Search Record",width=25)

    #Adding the Search Button into the grid
    self.search_button.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=6,pady=10)

    #Adding a Seperator to the grid
    ttk.Separator(orient="horizontal").grid(row=4,columnspan=6,sticky="ew")


    #Creating A Treeview
    self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(height=6)
    self.treeview['columns'] = ("One","Two","Three")
    self.treeview.column('#0',width=100)
    self.treeview.heading("#0", text="Testing")
    self.treeview.heading("One", text="Column A")
    self.treeview.heading("Two", text="Column B")
    self.treeview.heading("Three", text="Column C")
    self.treeview.grid(row=5,rowspan=5,column=0,columnspan=4,pady=(10,0))

    #Adding Default Data to The Treeview
    for i in range(10):
        self.treeview.insert("" , "end",    text="Line "+str(i), values=("1A","1b"))

    #Creating a treeview scrollbar
    self.vertical_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient='vertical')
    self.horizontal_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient='horizontal')

    #adding scrollbars to the grid
    self.vertical_scrollbar.grid(row=5,column=4,rowspan=6)
    self.horizontal_scrollbar.grid(row=10,column=0,columnspan=4)

    #configuring scrolls to treeview
    self.horizontal_scrollbar.configure(command=self.treeview.xview)
    self.vertical_scrollbar.configure(command=self.treeview.yview)

    #configuring treeview to Scrollbar
    self.treeview.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vertical_scrollbar.set)
    self.treeview.configure(xscrollcommand=self.horizontal_scrollbar.set)

    #Creating buttons
    self.view_all_record_btn = tk.Button(text="View All Records",width=15)
    self.add_record_btn = tk.Button(text="Add Record",width=15)
    self.edit_record_btn = tk.Button(text="Edit Record",width=15)
    self.delete_record_btn = tk.Button(text="Delete Record",width=15)
    self.upload_file_btn = tk.Button(text="Upload File",width=15)

    #Adding Buttons to the Grid
    self.view_all_record_btn.grid(row=5,column=5,pady=(10,0))
    self.add_record_btn.grid(row=6,column=5)
    self.edit_record_btn.grid(row=7,column=5)
    self.delete_record_btn.grid(row=8,column=5)
    self.upload_file_btn.grid(row=9,column=5,pady=(0,20))

    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that I have to add around 20 columns here but I only want to display 3-4 columns at a time rest columns will only be visible via scrollbar, my scrollbar for rows works fine but I can't figure out how to do that for columns

Comment: create two treeviews - one with columns visible all time, second with scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. If I create a treeview with all the columns visible it won't fit

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is dependent on your layout manager settings. For the grid system, I achieved what you wanted by adjusting my `.rowconfigure` and `.columnconfigure` settings of the relevant frame(s). If you get it right, you should be able to initially display the 2-3 columns and then use the xscrollbar to view the other 'hidden' 17-18 columns when need all in one treeview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry but I don't know how rowconfigure or columnconfigure is useful here, and anyways I have added my code in the question

Comment: @AnchalBhargava You should aim to share a minimum amount of code that can replicate your problem instead of a large chunk of an existing code. Can't help for now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Sun Bear 's answer and this [website](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html), I implemented the version of TreeView combined horizontal scrollbar. It's truly the problem of `.rowconfigure` and `. columnconfigure`. You can run the sample code below and you will know how it works. You also can see the execution result in the below image.

[result image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8vPu.png)

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *
    from Tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12))

# initialize a TreeView
myTreeView = ttk.Treeview(content)
myTreeView["columns"] = ("Index", "Value", "Price", "LAST_PRICE")
myTreeView.column("Index", stretch=False, width=150)
myTreeView.column("Value", stretch=False, width=100)
myTreeView.column("Price", stretch=False, width=100)
myTreeView.column("LAST_PRICE", stretch=False, width=100)
myTreeView.heading("Index", text="Index")
myTreeView.heading("Value", text="Value")
myTreeView.heading("Price", text="Price")
myTreeView.heading("LAST_PRICE", text="Last Price")

# attach a Horizontal (x) scrollbar to the frame
treeXScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(content, orient=HORIZONTAL)
treeXScroll.configure(command=myTreeView.xview)
myTreeView.configure(xscrollcommand=treeXScroll.set)

# initialize the Label and Entry
namelbl = ttk.Label(content, text="Name")
name = ttk.Entry(content)

# initialize Checkbuttons
onevar = BooleanVar()
twovar = BooleanVar()
threevar = BooleanVar()
onevar.set(True)
twovar.set(False)
threevar.set(True)
one = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="One", variable=onevar, onvalue=True)
two = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Two", variable=twovar, onvalue=True)
three = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Three", variable=threevar, onvalue=True)

# initialize Buttons
ok = ttk.Button(content, text="Okay")
cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Cancel")

# set position of all above objects by grid
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
myTreeView.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=2, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
treeXScroll.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=3, sticky=W + E)
namelbl.grid(column=3, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky=(N, W), padx=5)
name.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=(N, E, W), pady=5, padx=5)
one.grid(column=0, row=4)
two.grid(column=1, row=4)
three.grid(column=2, row=4)
ok.grid(column=3, row=4)
cancel.grid(column=4, row=4)

# Handling Resize
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
content.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
content.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
content.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

# run UI
root.mainloop()
```